# Как пройтись циклом по ответу json в JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

Всем привет, работая с jquery появился такой вопрос. Как можно пройтись циклом по мапе которая приходи с java? В jsp я делал, это таким образом:

```
<c:forEach items="${cartItems}" var="items">
                        <tr>
                        <td><a href="images/product/${items.key.imageName}"><img src="images/product/${items.key.imageName}" width=100></td>
                        <td><span class="name">${items.key.name}</span></td>
                        <td>${items.key.category.name}</td>
                        <td>${items.key.manufacturer.name}</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="count" value="${items.value}"></td>
                        <td>${items.key.price}</td>
                        <td><span id="totalPriceForOne">${items.key.price * items.value}</span></td>
                        <td><a href="removeItemFromCart?name=${items.key.name}">Remove item</a></td>
                        </tr>
```

Как можно сделать это в JQUery? С JSon мне приходит вот такая строка

```
> "cartItems":{"Product{id=3, name='ALLIANCE_SUNGLASSES', size='S',
> price=810.00, color='black', manufacturer=CompanyManufacturer{id=3,
> name='Luis Vuitton'}, category=Category{id=3, name='accessories'},
> imageName='3.png'}":1,"Product{id=2, name='45DAVID', size='L',
> price=100.00, color='blue', manufacturer=CompanyManufacturer{id=2,
> name='Collins'}, category=Category{id=2, name='jeans'},
> imageName='2.png'}":1}}
```

Где Product, это мой key, :цифра - это мой value. Я пытался как то так

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "cart",
        data: "name=" + name + "&count=" + count,
        success: function(data){

            $("#totalPrice").text("Total price: " + data['totalPrice'].toFixed(2)).wrap("<h4></h4>");
            $("#productCount").text("(" + data['productCount'] + ")");

            $.each(data['cartItems'], function(key, value) {
                alert(key.price + " " + value);
            });

        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

Но что то не вышло, как можно, это реализовать по типу как в jsp?

На данный момент я получаю вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что выводит console.log(data);

```
> cartItems: {Product{id=3, name='ALLIANCE_SUNGLASSES', size='S',
    > price=810.00, color='black', manufacturer=CompanyManufacturer{id=3,
    > name='Luis Vuitton'}, category=Category{id=3, name='accessories'},
    > imageName='3.png'}: 1, Product{id=2, name='45DAVID', size='L',
    > price=100.00, color='blue', manufacturer=CompanyManufacturer{id=2,
    > name='Collins'}, category=Category{id=2, name='jeans'},
    > imageName='2.png'}: 1}  productCount: 2  totalPrice: 910
    > __proto__: Object
```

Comment: "что то не вышло" - a что вышло?

Comment: `[data['cartItems']]` - что это значит?

Comment: Добавил, то что получаю на данный момент

Comment: что выводит в консоль `console.log(data);`?

Comment: data['cartIems'] - это мой элемент с json, моя мапа. Я обновил то что я получаю сейчас. Как мне достать после price из ключа?

Comment: добавил то, что выводит console.log(data);

Comment: никак. Возвращайте нормальный JSON, будет у Вас на клиенте нормальный объект со свойствами и подобъектами. Что такое "мапа" - я не знаю. Знаю "мавпа" - обезьяна по-украински.